# Error:string was not recognized as a valid datetime error in c#

Tags: c#

> Error:string was not recognized as a valid datetime error in c#

But I am using same code using in server system their working perfectly but in my local I got error so kindly

```
MTL_REQD_BY_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(mtlReqDate.Split('-')[1] + "-" + mtlReqDate.Split('-')[0] + "-" + mtlReqDate.Split('-')[2])
```

Comment: What is `mtlReqDate`?

Comment: Use: `MTL_REQD_BY_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(mtlReqDate);`

Answer (score 0):

Date format must be different on your Local machine.

Comment: Thank you, your correct when iam change my date format its working now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cultures of your system and the server are different.

Use the following approach for precise control:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(mtlReqDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.Current);
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) is the description of the DateTime.ParseExact method.

An overview of custom date and time format strings can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).